# How can you define a static data member of a class template?

Tags: c++, templates, static, static-members, class-template

I'd like to do this:

```
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    ...
    static double something_relevant = 1.5;
};
```

but I can't since `something_relevant` is not of integral type. It doesn't depend on `T`, but existing code depends on it being a static member of `S`.

Since S is template, I cannot put the definition inside a compiled file. How do I solve this problem ?

Comment: also applies to `std::string` type

Comment: Since c++11 the keyword inline has changed so that static variables can be initialized at the point of declaration. So the declaration for this would look like "inline static double something_relevant = 1.5;"

Comment: @user8991265 I believe inline variables are available since C++17, not C++11.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Just define it in the header:

```
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    static double something_relevant;
};

template <typename T>
double S<T>::something_relevant = 1.5;
```

Since it is part of a template, as with all templates the compiler will make sure it's only defined once.

Comment: @sbi: doesn't it violate the one definition rule ?

Comment: No, not if we're talking templates. Otherwise function templates would do so, too.

Comment: @sbi, @Prasoon: actually Prasoon seems to be the first. But I still accept sbi's because of the comment about the ODR (which was my primary concern).

Comment: @Johannes: How do you get at the exact times? For me, it just shows "1 hour ago" each. I know I can sort them by "oldest" and "newest", and it will show the exact times in three days (until then it says "2 days ago"), but I have no idea how I get at the exact times _now_.

Comment: @sbi just hover over the text :)

Comment: @Johannes Schaub -litb: Frankly speaking when I saw sbi's answer the last two lines were `template <typename T> double something_relevant<T> = 1.5;` which is syntactically incorrect(he might have missed something );-). So I decided to post my solution.

Comment: @sbi: If you think there's something wrong in my last comment, please do mention :-)

Comment: @Johannes: Dammit, I'm here for a year and I didn't know that! What else am I missing? (I still remember the shame when I discovered that the two numbers that appear when I click on the number of votes aren't a bug, but a feature.) `<goes_playing>` Wow, when I hover over your name, I see your rep! I didn't know that one either. @Prasoon: No, you're right, I iteratively arrived at where it is now. (That's why I up-voted your answer, BTW.)

Comment: @Johannes: Ah, I always wondered what that stood for.(And, yes, Imagine is a wonderful song.) @James: That rang a bell: ["My hair style calls into immediate question all my judgements."](http://groups.google.de/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/msg/f7e901ce6e8a86c0) (near the end of that posting)

Comment: What if class is enclosed into namespace?

Comment: @fnc12: Then you need to put stuff into said namespace?

Comment: @sbi - To muddy the waters, how do we initialize 5 or 6 specializations of `T`? I've been trying the {simple|obvious} answer at [How to initialize a static member of a parametrized-template class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11153182/608639), but Clang keeps failing the link due to mulitply defined symbols because the header is used in several source files. In our case the class variable is `static const` and it is like things are escaping translation unit scope.

Comment: @jww: If you define static members of specific instances, rather than the base template's, you will have to put them into cpp files. There's tricks around this, but they add hard-to-read warts to your code.

Comment: if multiple cpp includes this header, and in each of the cpp, instantiation `S` of `T=int` happens in each TU, will they share the same static `S<int>::something_relevant`? Isn't each TU has its own definition of the  `S<int>::something_relevant`?

Comment: @dragonxlwang: Your compiler/linker is required to fold all these instances from different translation units into a single one in the same way it is required to fold all the functions generated from function templates in each translation unit.

Comment: Imagine I have 5 template arguments with SFINAE stuff and 10 static members. Is there a way to not repeat the whole template<...> thing?

Comment: @Osman-pasha Nope, there isn't. It's a pain in the neck to write this.

Comment: @sbi what if the static member to be initialized is private ?

Comment: @Bemipefe Then it cannot be accessed from outside the class (except for friendship)? Why do you ask?

Comment: @sbi My concern was not being able to initialize a __private static__ member like you suggested (from "outside" the class) but surprisingly your code works also in this case.

Comment: Oh. I see. Yes, of course it works! This is not considered accessing a private member. You are defining and initializing a previously declared object, and even private objects have to be defined and should be initialized.

Answer (score 86):

Since C++17, you can now declare the static member to be `inline`, which will define the variable in the class definition:

```
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    ...
    static inline double something_relevant = 1.5;
};
```

live: https://godbolt.org/g/bgSw1u

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Short and precise. See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Static_data_members for more information.

Comment: One wonders why the standards committee felt it necessary to require an extra keyword instead of just making the previously illegal static declaration legal.

Comment: This is not possible if the type of the member is of the templated class itself, as the class is not yet fully defined.

Answer (score 41):

This will work

```
template <typename T>
 struct S
 {

     static double something_relevant;
 };

 template<typename T>
 double S<T>::something_relevant=1.5;
```

Comment: I didn't define the something_relevant variable(I removed ```template<typename T>
 double S<T>::something_relevant=1.5;)``` compiler throwing error.Can you please tell me what is the reason?

Comment: This will introduce a copy of the variable in each module that include these lines. And how can one make sure that the variable is present only in one shared module, and other modules reference it?