# Is it possible to have an "auto" member variable?

Tags: c++, struct, auto

For example I wanted to have a variable of type `auto` because I'm not sure what type it will be.

When I try to declare it in class/struct declaration it's giving me this error:

> Cannot deduce auto type. Initializer required

Is there a way around it?

```
struct Timer {

    auto start;

};
```

Comment: Isn't that what templates are for?

Comment: When do you find out what type it will be? Compile time or run time? Can you give us some context? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is `sizeof(Timer)`?

Comment: What would that _mean_?

Comment: @Oleksiy plz give more description. Why can't you decide its type?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can, but you have to declare it `static` and `const`:

```
struct Timer {
    static const auto start = 0;
};
```

[A working example in Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=859d479cb184d32b3c61e8e97bbcf5b5-3afcc3bc1f2cd10b247c33a6cde9edad).

With this limitation, you therefore cannot have `start` as a non-static member, and cannot have different values in different objects.

If you want different types of `start` for different objects, better have your class as a template

```
template<typename T>
struct Timer {
    T start;
};
```

If you want to deduce the type of `T`, you can make a factory-like function that does the type deduction.

```
template<typename T>
Timer<typename std::decay<T>::type> MakeTimer(T&& startVal) {   // Forwards the parameter
   return Timer<typename std::decay<T>::type>{std::forward<T>(startVal)};
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f6834280638446e5838f1e9b72d128e1-3afcc3bc1f2cd10b247c33a6cde9edad).

Comment: Is there anything fundamental that prevents auto non static members from being allowed in the standard assuming they are initialized at point of declaration ?

Comment: @user3882729 Imo an `auto` member would make it pretty unclear that it's actually a template, unlike a function template which just have `auto` at it's first line.

Answer (score 6):

This is what the [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) has to say about using `auto` for member variables, in section `7.1.6.4 auto specifier` paragraph `4`:

> The auto type-specifier can also be used in declaring a variable in the condition of a selection statement (6.4) or an iteration statement (6.5), in the type-specifier-seq in the new-type-id or type-id of a new-expression (5.3.4), in a for-range-declaration, and **in declaring a static data member with a brace-or-equal-initializer that appears within the member-specification of a class definition (9.4.2)**.

Since it must be initialized this also means that it must be [`const`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9657064). So something like the following will work:

```
struct Timer
{
  const static int start = 1;
};
```

I don't think that gets you too much though. Using template as Mark suggests or now that I think about it some more maybe you just need a [variant type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type). In that case you should check out [`Boost.Variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [`Boost.Any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any.html).

Answer (score 6):

If you declare a class in a lambda expression, you can infer the types of member variables using `decltype`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

auto generic_class = [](auto width1, auto height1) {
    class local_class {
        public:
        decltype(width1) width;
        decltype(height1) height;
    } local;
    local.width = width1;
    local.height = height1;
    return local;
};

int main()
{
    auto obj1 = generic_class(3,std::string("Hello!"));
    auto obj2 = generic_class(std::vector<int>{1,2},true);
    cout << obj1.height << "\n";
    cout << obj2.width[0] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code can really mess with someone's head

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it would be nice, if a future version of the C++ standard allowed `auto` also on non-static members, if an initializer is present, as in this simple example:

```
class C {
    auto a { 0.0 };
    auto b { 3U };
};
```

This would be equivalent to:

```
class C {
    decltype(0.0) a { 0.0 };
    decltype(3U) b { 3U };
};
```

and would save some typing in certain cases, especially, where the initializing expressions are not as simple as here. Of course, the in-class initializers can later be overridden in constructors, but for the typing of the class members, the in-class initializers should take precedence.

Comment: I second that  ! Now that we can declare almost any variable with auto, like:
  auto varName = DatyType { value };
we should be able to do the same for class members

Answer (score 2):

No. Each constructor could have its own initializer for `start`, so there could be no consistent type to use.

If you *do* have a usable expression, you can use that:

```
struct Timer {

   Foo getAFoo();

   delctype(Timer().getAFoo().Bar()) start;

   Timer() : start(getAFoo().Bar()) { /***/ }
};
```

Comment: Is there any way of writing this without repeating `getAFoo().Bar()`?

Comment: @Eric: Of course, just add a member `auto getAFooBar() { return getAFoo().Bar(); }` and use that instead. The example was showing off that even more complex variants still work.

Answer (score 0):

Indirectly, provided that you don't reference a member of the class.

This can also now be achieved through deduction guides, these were introduced in C++17 and have recently (finally) support in VC++ has been added (clang and GCC already had it).

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

For example:

```
template <typename>
struct CString;

template <typename T, unsigned N>
struct CString<std::array<T, N>>
{
    std::array<T, N> const Label;

    CString(std::array<T, N> const & pInput) : Label(pInput) {}
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
CString(std::array<T, N> const & pInput) -> CString<std::array<T, N>>;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/LyL7UW

This can be used to deduce class member types in a similar manner to auto. Although the member variables need to be Dependant somehow on the constructor arguments.

Comment: This doesn't seem related, really. There is no deduction of the member's type here. Rather, the member is explicitly typed, although it just so happens that said type depends on template arguments. What done here is deducing those template arguments from the constructor call, not the type of the member. The type of the member is set in stone by that of the class; it's not automatic at all.

Comment: The member type is deduced from the deduction guide, not explicitly typed.

The question specifically said "I wanted to have a variable of type auto because I'm not sure what type it will be."
Deduction guides address this, provided that the constructor can be used for deduction (which is likely but not garenteed).

This is actually similar to the top rated answers factory function. So its not just me who thinks this may assist the questioner.