# Why should const static variables initialised inside struct?

Tags: c++

I'm a Cpp beginner and couldn't understand the following:

```
struct A{
int i;
static int j;
}

int A::j = 20;
```

Here,
    I understood why static varible cannot be initialised inside `A` and it has to be initialised outised of `A` using scope resolution. (That is the point memory for `j` will be allocated and value is initialised) and `j` here doesn't add to the `sizeof(A)` as it is a static varible and has static storage for all the objects.

Consider the following script:

```
struct B{
int a;
const static int b = 20;
}
```

Here,
    I'm forced to initialize the value of `b` in the struct declaration directly. Why it is like this if static variable is of `const` type?
If I try to define this variable outside the scope of `B`, then it is throwing a compiler error stating that there is a previous declaration of `b`. Here when the memory for `b` is actually allocated and why  it has to be initialized within the declaration and why can't it cannot be initialized using a `::` operator like normal static variable?

Comment: You aren't forced to initialize the value of `b` in the declaration. `const int B::b = 20;` will work fine. I suspect you forgot to add `;` at the end of your `struct` declaration.

Comment: What happens when you try to initialize `b` outside of `B`? Do you get a compiler error? What is the error?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux if the static variable is of `const static` type, why can I give the value of the variable inside unlike normal `static` variable?

Comment: Can you make your bottom chunk of code complete by adding the `int B::b = 20;`, or whatever you used to initialize it?

Comment: @Mbeginner That question has been asked here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656941/why-cant-i-initialize-non-const-static-member-or-static-array-in-class

Comment: Voting to close as the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: I'm so sorry everyone. I did it wrong in initlaising. Its working perfect as Francois told.

Answer (score 3):

You misread the error. The error should be something like "you have a **conflicting** declaration", meaning you declared it inline const but the definition doesn't have a const. So just do this:

```
const int B::b = 20;
```