# Why is this static member variable not valid and causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

I'm getting a segmentation fault and I don't know why, I had thought the variable is being initialised properly.

I want a class to provide access to a global configuration manager class, so I have the following factory class set out below.  There is a means (via the `setConfigurationManagerForTesting()` method) of injecting a different `ConfigurationManager` class into the factory that will be returned in order to facilitate easier testing.  It is not called by the code that has the failure.

```
 /**
 * @brief Factory class that creates a global instance of ConfigurationManager
 */
class ConfigurationManagerFactory {
  public:
    /**
     * @brief Get the global ConfigurationManager
     * @return The global ConfigurationManager
     */
    static ConfigurationManager &getConfigurationManager();

    /**
     * @brief Set the ConfigurationManager to a defined instance, to allow for testing
     *
     * @param configurationManager The ConfigurationManager that should replace the default one
     */
    static void setConfigurationManagerForTesting(ConfigurationManager *configurationManager);


// commented out to allow for trying to track down the failure
//      private: 
    ConfigurationManagerFactory() {}
    static ConfigurationManager configurationManager;
    static ConfigurationManager *configurationManagerPtr;
};
```

Here is the implementation in the `.cpp` file:

```
ConfigurationManager ConfigurationManagerFactory::configurationManager;
ConfigurationManager *ConfigurationManagerFactory::configurationManagerPtr = nullptr;

ConfigurationManager &ConfigurationManagerFactory::getConfigurationManager() {
    if (configurationManagerPtr == nullptr) {
        configurationManagerPtr = &configurationManager;
    }
    return *configurationManagerPtr;
}

void ConfigurationManagerFactory::setConfigurationManagerForTesting(ConfigurationManager *testingConfigurationManager) {
    configurationManagerPtr = testingConfigurationManager;
}
```

The initialisation of the static member variables is as per that set out [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019856/c-initialize-static-variables-in-class).

The failing code within a Google test:

```
std::cout << "ok so far 1" << std::endl;
ConfigurationManager &cm = ConfigurationManagerFactory::getConfigurationManager();
std::cout << "ok so far 2" << std::endl;
ASSERT_EQ(&cm, ConfigurationManagerFactory::configurationManagerPtr);
std::cout << "ok so far 3" << std::endl;
cm.getConfiguration();
std::cout << "ok so far 4" << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
ok so far 1
ok so far 2
ok so far 3
:test FAILED
```

The test fails with exit code 139, which is a segmentation fault.  I can't check (don't know how to check) that the address to which the `configurationManagerPtr` variable points is valid, but the assertion shows that it points at the static member variable.

The `getConfiguration()` method where the failure occurs simply returns (by value) a member variable of the `ConfigurationManager`:

```
class ConfigurationManager {
  public:
    ConfigurationManager();
    virtual ~ConfigurationManager() {}

    virtual boost::property_tree::ptree getConfiguration();

  protected:
    boost::property_tree::ptree configuration;
};

boost::property_tree::ptree ConfigurationManager::getConfiguration() {
    return configuration;
}
```

Comment: Does `ConfigurationManager` have a copy or move constructor? I'm suspecting something related to that.

Comment: No, it's just got the structure as shown above at the bottom of the post, plus a couple of other unrelated methods.

Comment: It works fine when I changed the type of `ConfigurationManager::configuration` to `int` so perhaps the problem lies in `boost::property_tree::ptree`.

Comment: Do you call setConfigurationManagerForTesting() to set the stub? If so, are you sure that the object, pointer to which you pass to setConfigurationManagerForTesting(), is still alive when you execute the test?

Comment: Just installed Boost and tried your code. No problems encountered.