# How to initialize static variable out of the class with conditions on file reading?

Tags: c++, static, conditional-statements

I have a class with static variables and I wish to initialize those variables depending on a value written in a file, something like this :

```
reading file to fill condition (example : toto = 1)
if (toto == 1)
    static_variable = something
```

Since it is static variable is has to be done outside of the class.

How could I do that ?

Comment: Write a function: `T X::static_variable = f();`.

Comment: You can have static variables inside classes: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5019896/1829943 and you can initialize a variable using a function