# C++ tuple linking issue: undefined reference

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

I suppose that there is something terribly wrong with this code. It will compile but does not get linked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

class Table_class
{
    public:
    constexpr static std::tuple<int, unsigned int, unsigned short> table[3]
    = {std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3),
        std::make_tuple(4, 5, 6),
        std::make_tuple(7, 8, 9)};
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::get<0>(Table_class::table[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The error that shows up is this:

```
[31m/tmp/ccDiIuPv.o: In function `main':
file.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `Table_class::table'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Compilation Failed
```

How can this be corrected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ initialize static variables in class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019856/c-initialize-static-variables-in-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not terribly wrong. Your code is (will be) perfectly legal in C++17. However, before C++17, static constexpr data members need to be defined outside of class, so find somewhere and add the following definition:

```
constexpr std::tuple<int, unsigned int, unsigned short> Table_class::table[3];
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9T2yVj1ODDVxOUzS).

As usual, variable definition should not be in a header file.

Comment: The solution works and solves the problem, but, when used as part of a .h or .cpp file, it has this drawback of having to define that line in the routine that calls it. Fingers crossed for C++17 !!!

Answer (score 1):

It's a common source of linking errors.
You have to define the table outside the class definition, to make the linker find it. 
A simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

class Table_class
{
    public:
    constexpr static std::tuple<int, unsigned int, unsigned short> table = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3);

};

constexpr std::tuple<int, unsigned int, unsigned short> Table_class::table;
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::get<0>(Table_class::table);
    return 0;
}
```