# Multiple classes need access to a static variable

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, linker, dependencies

We have classes A, B and C, all of which need access to a static variable `staticVariable` in class D.

Moreover, class A needs to have an instance of classes B and C like this:

```
    class A{
    public:
    B instanceB;
    C instanceC;
    };
```

Class D hold the static variable of object type `T`:

```
    class D{
    public:
    D() {
    staticVariable.init();
    };
    static T staticVariable;
    };
```

In the example classes B and C can be empty placeholder classes:

```
    class B{
    };

    class C{
    };
```

The main function creates an instance of A:

```
    int main(){
    A a;
    /*...*/
    }
```

Again, classes A, B and C need access to `staticVariable`. I've tried multiple approaches including inheritance and friend functions, however I always get dependency issues or linker errors I don't quite understand:

```
    Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static class T 
    D::staticVariable" (?window@D@@2VT@sf@@A)   SortingAlgorithms    
    C:\Users\Dusan\source\repos\SortingAlgorithms\SortingAlgorithms\B.obj
```

is being reported in .obj files of classes A, B and C.

I'm not sure if I need an instance of `D` in `main`.
How do I implement this error-free?
And how do you do it for `static` objects that call a function for initialization?
I meant if the function is of the same class as the object you're trying to initialize, and is non-static, I can't seem to be able to call `staticVariable.init();`

Comment: Linker errors? Like these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019856/initialize-static-variables-in-c-class

Comment: Please show one of your failed attempts. It is not clear what problems you are struggling with. You can acces it via `D::staticVariable`. However, note that in the code you posted the static member is not defined. Whether this is also the issue in your real code we can only know when you post a [mcve]

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes I clarified the code, 'staticVariable' is initialized in constructor of D.

Comment: the line you added changes nothing about my comment. You need a definition of the static variable. Static variables are not initialized in the constructor. Please post a [mcve] and the resulting error message

Comment: @yomag1234 You don't initialize in a constructor (static things are like global, they are not bound to an object). You have to initialize them just outside the class (in your implementation file, like `Type Class::Variable = Value;`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I added the linker error now if that helps.

Comment: sorry, but thats just a fragment of the full message. The full message contains detailed information on what is wrong in your code.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes so if static variables are more objects that call functions for initialization, I can do it anywhere?

Comment: You should indent your code properly.

Comment: @yomag1234 also non-static members are not initialized in the body of the constructor (though thats a different issue, only semi related). See eg here for definition of static members: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536372/defining-static-members-in-c

Comment: @yomag1234 You mean if the static member is a class-type object itself? It is similar, initialize it the same way by calling a constructor. Just don't "do it anywhere," do it in the implementation (.cpp) file that also implements member functions of class D (that goes also when the static member is not a class object)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I clarified that staticVariable is an object type and included the whole error code, hope this helps.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes Thank you that's what I meant.

Comment: yes I saw that. Your question can be considered as duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536372/defining-static-members-in-c. I just can't flag it anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I'm not sure if I need an instance of D in main.*

You don't. `static` variables are global, they are shared by all the instances of the same class and you don't need to instantiate a class to be able to use such variables so they must be initialized regardless of class instantiation. That being the case they need to be initialized outside the class.

> *How do I implement this error-free?*

Something like:

```
class B{};

class C{};

class A{
public:
    B instanceB;
    C instanceC;
};

class D{
public:
    D(){};
    static int staticVariable;
};

int D::staticVariable = 10; //<-- here, outside the class

int main()
{
    //no instance of D needed
    std::cout << D::staticVariable; // prints 10
    D::staticVariable++;
    std::cout << D::staticVariable; // prints 11 
}
```

---

> *And how do you do it for `static` objects that call a function for initialization?*
> *I meant if the function is of the same class as the object you're trying to initialize, and is non-static, I can't seem to be able to call `staticVariable.init();`*

It's the same principle, you declare the object static within the class and initialize it outside:

```
class A{
public:
    void init(){std::cout << "Do Something";} //non-static method
};

class D{
public:
    static A obj; //declare
};

A D::obj{};  //<-- initialize outside the class

int main()
{
    D::obj.init();  // prints 'Do Something'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// in D.hpp
class D {
public:
  D() { ... }; // staticVariable is static, so the ctor has no business initializing it
  void init();  

  static int staticVariable;
  static D staticD;
};

// in D.cpp
#include "D.hpp"

int D::staticVariable = 10;
// Immediatly invoked initializing lambda expression
D D::staticD = []{ D tmp; tmp.init(); return tmp; }();
```