# How to initialize a static member of a parametrized-template class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

I don't think my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229883/static-member-initialization-in-a-template-class).

what I try to do:

```
template<const char* szFunctionName>
class CReentranceLock
{
public:
    CReentranceLock(){}
    ~CReentranceLock(){}
    bool isLocked(){return s_bLock;}
    void setLocked(bool b)
    {
        const bool Result=(bool)InterlockedCompareExchange(
                    (unsigned long *)&s_bLock, b, !b);
    }

private:
    static bool s_bLock;
};

template<const char* szFunctionName>
bool CReentranceLock<const char*szFunctionName>::s_bLock=false; 
// error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'szFunctionName'
```

implying that all instances of CReentranceLock would have their own static, relying on the const char address of the function name passed as a parameter of the template.

and that could be used like this:

```
void CMyObject::InAnyFunction()
{
    const char* szFunctionName = __FUNCTION__; 
    CReentranceLock<szFunctionName> lock; // Edit: <- this doesn't work
    if(lock.isLocked()) return;
    lock.setLocked(true);
    /// business code
   lock.setLocked(false);
}
```

well that's only the theory...
and unfortunately this doesn't compile under visual 2010, at the line where I try to initialize the statics.

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'szFunctionName'
```

what am I doing or thinking wrong ?

PS: and I am not dealing with the fact that reentrance is smelling like an awful design (in MFC), I know, I am lost in the middle of it ;-)

**Edit**: though the answer below is good, and the definition compiles... my use in `CMyObject::InAnyFunction()` with a const char * as a template-parameter available at compile time seems to be wrong. :-(

Comment: The member `s_bLock` itself does not exist unless you instance a `CReentranceLock`. the `szFunctionName` is only a placeholder name that does not exist (as the compiler warns you). Try `const char Foo[] = {"Foo"}; bool CReentranceLock<Foo>::s_bLock=false;` instead. (but you will set only the `s_bLock` of the `Foo` instance type of `CReentranceLock`).

Comment: @StephaneRolland : you're right, learned something.

Comment: @StephaneRolland: Are you suggesting that `const char *` is convertible to an `int`?

Comment: @dirkgently well, that's what I intimately think, though it may depends whether you are on a 32 or 64 bits system. on a 64 bits system, I think it's a 64 bits integer.

Comment: @Yochai, no pb man, you could have keep your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool CReentranceLock<const char*szFunctionName>::s_bLock=false;
```

This should be:

```
bool CReentranceLock<szFunctionName>::s_bLock=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the line to

`bool CReentranceLock<szFunctionName>::s_bLock=false;`

Comment: Nope, you need to use template parameter (even if templated) there.

Comment: Sorry about that. A typo. Since the answer's already provided, i'll edit it