# error: no match for 'operator=' . Trying to inherit from base class and initialize from base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I'm trying to declare a base class called `BASE` and I'm having trouble using the inherited types `A` and `B` inside of the `BASE` class. I'm getting the error

```
|In member function 'NODE& NODE::operator=(const NODE&)':|
16|warning: no return statement in function returning non-void|
In member function 'void BASE<T, SIZE>::init_A(int) [with T = NODE, unsigned int SIZE = 2u]':|
96|instantiated from here|
39|error: no match for 'operator=' in 'A<NODE, 2u>::DATA[index] = a'|
13|note: candidates are: NODE& NODE::operator=(const NODE&)|


#include <iostream>

class NODE
{
        private:

        public:

        NODE(){}
        ~NODE(){}

};

template <class T, size_t SIZE>
class A;
template <class T, size_t SIZE>

class BASE
{
    protected:

        static T DATA[SIZE];

    public:

        BASE()
        {

        }
        ~BASE(){}
        void init_A(int index)
        {                       
            A<T,SIZE>::DATA[index] = T();            
        }        
};
template <class T, size_t SIZE>
class A : public BASE<T,SIZE>
{
     protected:         

    public:


        A(){}
        ~A(){}

};

template <class T, size_t SIZE>
T BASE<T,SIZE>::DATA[SIZE] = {};
int main()
{
    BASE<NODE,2> base;

    base.init_A(0);    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `A<T,SIZE>::DATA[index] = a;` inside `void init_A(int index);`

Comment: I've tried different ways to make it work. Sorry about the comments all over the place.

Comment: Start with `return ( *this );` in `NODE::operator=(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can make it compile, but it might not do what you want.
The first problem is you assignment operator promises to return something and doesn't:

```
NODE& NODE::operator=(const NODE&)
{

}
```

Try this

```
NODE& NODE::operator=(const NODE&)
{
    return *this;
}
```

The second problem is

```
A<T,SIZE> a;
A<T,SIZE>::DATA[index] = a;
```

The `DATA` is an array of `T`, not an `A<T,SIZE>`.
Try this

```
A<T,SIZE>::DATA[index] = T();
```

<strike>Finally you need to declare your statics somewhere.</strike>  

Finally you need to define your statics somewhere.See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229883/static-member-initialization-in-a-class-template)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229883/static-member-initialization-in-a-class-template But be warned other things will go wrong - it's not clear what you are trying to do. Come back with a new question if you get stuck further

Comment: Why have they all got their own static data? ie static T DATA[SIZE] in 3 places

Comment: He needs to _define_ his static members somewhere.  They're declared in the class definition.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks: a thinko - how do I do markout to cross something out?

Comment: @lost_with_coding is "editted" a new question. Because there is no question

Comment: @doctorlove No its just the solution that compiles although the code is essentially useless.