# Xcode 9 only - How to resolve the [-Wundefined-var-template] warning caused by static variable in a class template?

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode9

The sample code compiles without warning or error on Windows and Linux. It starts to get the `-Wundefined-var-template` warning in XCode 9.

foo.h:

```
template <typename T>
struct myClass
{
    static const char* name;
};
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"
template<>
const char *myClass<int>::name = "int";
```

---

```
warning: instantiation of variable 'myClass<int>::name' required here, but no definition is available [-Wundefined-var-template] 

note: forward declaration of template entity is here 
    static const char *name; 
                       ^ 
note: add an explicit instantiation declaration to suppress this warning if 'myClass<int>::name' is explicitly instantiated in another translation unit
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, because static variables cannot be inlined, so they cannot be handled in the same way as functions. Please see "What I tried but didn't work" section in my own answer.

Comment: they can when they are template members. Here is a better dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229883/static-member-initialization-in-a-class-template

Comment: ...hm actually now I not sure anymore, because `myClass<int>` is a concrete type, not a template anymore.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, tobi303. I tried the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229883/static-member-initialization-in-a-class-template, as mentioned in the second bullet in "What I tried but didn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What I tried but didn't work:**

- Moving the code in foo.cpp to foo.h resulted in "duplicate code" error at link-time, because foo.h was included by multiple files.
- Adding the following code in the header file can resolve the warning, but the code fails at runtime.

  ```
  template<T>
  const char *myClass<T>::name = "";
  ```

**What worked in the end:**

foo.h:

```
template <typename T>
struct myClass
{
    static const char* name;
};

template <>
struct myClass<int>
{
    static const char* name;
};
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"
const char *myClass<int>::name = "int";
```

Comment: how does this solve the problem? You've simply defined a specialization of the entire template, which defies the point of the template