# Static member initialization in a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I need to initialize a static bool inside of a template class and I tried to do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3229904/5337213). The only difference I can see is that I have a constraint on type parameter T but this causes a compilation error, why? How can I solve this?

Code is the following:

```
template<class T, class = typename enable_if<is_any_integral<T>::value>::type>
class fraction {
    static bool auto_reduce;

    // ...
};

template<class T, class = typename enable_if<is_any_integral<T>::value>::type>
bool fraction<T>::auto_reduce = true;
```

And the error is:

> error: nested name specifier '`fraction<T>::`' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization
>   `bool fraction<T>::auto_reduce = true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe simpler

```
template<class T, class V>
bool fraction<T, V>::auto_reduce = true;
```

When you write

```
template<class T, class = typename enable_if<is_any_integral<T>::value>::type>
class fraction
```

you say that `fraction` is a class with two type template paramenters; the `std::enable_if` if part is useful to assign a default value to the second parameter (and to permit the enable/not enable SFINAE works) but `fraction` is and remain a template `class` with two parameters, you have to cite both and there is no need to repeat the enable/not enable/default part for second parameter initializing `auto_reduce`.

Comment: But do you have to necessarily introduce `V`? Will `template<class T, typename = void>` do?

Comment: @水飲み鳥 - take in count that `V` (as `T`) is just the name of a template parameter; you can also change names, if you want, and initialize `auto_reduce` as `template<class A, class B> bool fraction<A, B>::auto_reduce = true;`; I've named the second as `V` because the default value is `void` but is absolutely arbitrary. In class declaration you can avoid to use the name of the second parameters because isn't used (is just a SFINAE trick to enable/not enable); but externally initializing a `static` variable you have to reference it so you have to give it an (arbitrary) name.

Comment: @max66 Thanks for the comment. It seems that initializing the `static` requires the *full type qualification* of the class template `fraction`: in this case, two type parameters (as you said).