# C++ what's the correct way to define static member

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a static member in a normal member function. But the compiler report some errors. Pls take a look at this code

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class MyClass {
private:
  static std::allocator<T> alloc;
  T *p;
public:
  void assign(T e) {
    p = alloc.allocate(1);
    alloc.construct(p, e);
  }
};
```

and this is how I use it:

```
#include 'myclass.h'

int main() {
  MyClass<int> cls;
  cls.assign(4);

};
```

And the compiler give this error:

```
/Users/liuziqi/CLionProjects/cpplearning/src/tt.h:17:9: warning: instantiation of variable 'MyClass<int>::alloc' required here, but no definition is available [-Wundefined-var-template]
    p = alloc.allocate(1);
        ^
/Users/liuziqi/CLionProjects/cpplearning/src/main.cpp:49:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'MyClass<int>::assign' requested here
  cls.assign(4);
      ^
/Users/liuziqi/CLionProjects/cpplearning/src/tt.h:13:28: note: forward declaration of template entity is here
  static std::allocator<T> alloc;
                           ^
/Users/liuziqi/CLionProjects/cpplearning/src/tt.h:17:9: note: add an explicit instantiation declaration to suppress this warning if 'MyClass<int>::alloc' is explicitly instantiated in another translation unit
    p = alloc.allocate(1);
```

I can not figure out which part is wrong.....I have defined that static member and any member function should be able to use it. Is this error relevant to **template**? (I've just learned template and not sure If I use it correctly.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I'm going to take a shot at describing what the warning is referring to in addition to answering the "how to fix it" question (which certainly has been answered many times before)...*

Because MyClass is a template, the compiler expects all the code for the templated class to be available in the same file (`myclass.h`).   Since you only declare but do not define alloc in `myclass.h`, the compiler assumes you made a mistake.  It's not absolutely required to be there (hence the *warning* and not *error*) and you could disable the warning if you define the variable elsewhere, but it's almost certainly just a mistake.

If you're using c++17, the easiest way to deal with this is to declare the static member as inline, so it will be defined right there:

```
  static inline std::allocator<T> alloc;
```

live: https://godbolt.org/g/cr1aUP

Prior to C++17, you would explicitly define the variable in `myclass.h`:

```
template<typename T>
std::allocator<T> MyClass<T>::alloc;
```

live: https://godbolt.org/g/2Znqst

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229883/static-member-initialization-in-a-class-template

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about 'declare' and 'define' here. I thought my declaration of alloc inside the class template is already an 'definition', because that's how I normally define a member of class. Why still need to define it outside? (And it looks the same as my 'declaration' inside the template.....what's the different here?) .       Is it the problem of the template? (in other word, if we're not writing a template, but a class here, then the definition inside the class should be enough)

Comment: static variables are only defined once per class, not once per object.  Prior to C++17, that required a static member definition outside the class definition.   It's very similar to how `extern` works in a non-class setting, if you're familiar with that.     If this weren't in a template situation, it's quite normal to have the definition in another file (a .cpp file), but since the static variable needs to be defined for each *instantiation* of the class MyClass<int> needs one, MyClass<double> needs a different one, etc... then the definition is expected in the .h file so the instantiating...

Comment: caller can generate the code to create the static member for the exact instantiated type of the templated class being used.