# Does constant static member variables of a class or a struct in C++ need not be defined separately?

Tags: c++, static, constants

Does constant static member variables of a class or a struct in C++ need not be defined separately?

Is this correct?

```
struct test
{
    const static int x;
};

int test::x;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializing private static members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members)

Comment: @Martin: Not quite a duplicate as `x` isn't private here. (Although this doesn't matter in the linked question, the questioner in that question originally though it did.)

Comment: @Charles Bailey: The answer to the question is the same. There is no point in providing the same answers when it already exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No that's not correct. The definition must match the declaration and `x` is `const int`, not `int`. As a `const` variable of POD type it also needs to be initialized. E.g.

```
const int test::x = 0;
```

As a `const static` member of integral type, it is also allowed to supply the initializer in the definition of the class instead.

Comment: I was going to answer, but there's no point. Everything is said above!

Comment: Charles: Thanks. If I can initialize a const static variable in class itself, then why this probelm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563897/c-static-constant-string-class-member

Comment: @Krishnan: You are only allowed to initialize data members in the class body if they are `static` members of `const` integral or `const` enumeration types. `std::string` does not meet these requirements. The accepted answer of the question that you link to says exactly this.

Comment: Note that even if you initialize a `static const` integral type in the declaration, technically you must still provide a single definition somewhere if it's used in the program. 9.4.2/4 says, "The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is used in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer."  However, most (all?) compilers don't seem to care.