# Does Visual Studio 2010 C++ Fully Support in-Class const Variables?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, scope, initialization

This question is closely related to a question that was previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365826/why-doesnt-the-visual-studio-2010-debugger-see-static-const-class-members?noredirect=1#comment23467049_16365826).

In order for the Visual Studio 2010 C++ debugger to resolve in-class-initialized const variables, a global *definition* for the variable must be supplied.

---

e.g.

Here is the class definition:

```
class B{
  public:
   static const int m_b=100;
};
```

Here is the global scope definition of the member:

```
const int B::m_b;
```

---

Without the global definition the code works but the debugger cannot see m_b within B's methods.

However, this leads to another problem.  In non-trivial header file inclusion arrangements (full code given below), Visual Studio produces this link error:

```
error LNK2005: "public: static int const B::m_b" (?m_b@B@@2HB) already defined in a.obj
1>a.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

However GCC compiles, links, and runs the code successfully.

Here is the code in question:

file a.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"

const int B::m_b;

int main()
{
    B b;
    std::cout << b.m_b;
    return 0;
}
```

file a.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "b.h"
```

file b.cpp:

```
#include "b.h"
```

file b.h:

```
#pragma once

class B {
public:
    static const int m_b = 100;
};
```

Here are the linker options (default VS10 console program):

```
/OUT:"a.exe" 
/NOLOGO "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" 
/MANIFEST 
/ManifestFile:"Debug\a.exe.intermediate.manifest" 
/ALLOWISOLATION 
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" 
/DEBUG 
/PDB:"Debug\a.pdb" 
/PGD:"Debug\a.pgd" 
/TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

Here are the compiler options (default VS10 console program):

```
/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "_MBCS" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t
/Zc:forScope /Fp"Debug\sndbx.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd
/analyze- /errorReport:queue
```

Again, this builds, links, and runs successfully with GCC ( g++ a.cpp b.cpp ). The code I've supplied is complete so it can be copied, pasted, and run.

Comment: Remember `#pragma once` is not standard. So VS might not support it. Leading to multiple inclusions of header files.

Comment: @Named VS does support `#pragma once`.

Comment: @Angew Yes It seems it does. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4141z1cx.aspx

Comment: In addition to @Agnew's comment I also tried this with standard "guards" just to be sure and the result was the same.

Comment: This is still a problem with VS2013.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't put non-template definitions of data in header files, because you will get multiple definition errors at link time.  Whether the variable is a member variable or a static member variable or a const static member variable doesn't change this at all.

Put the definition in exactly one compilation unit, just like you would for any other singleton.

---

This actually looks like a Visual C++ bug.  It would have helped considerably if you had shown the complete error message, namely

> b.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int const B::m_b" (?m_b@B@@2HB) already defined in a.obj
>   a.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

The symbol would not be defined anywhere in b.obj if the compiler were working right.

---

Furthermore, attempting to use `__declspec(selectany)` tells us that the compiler knows this is not a definition:

> r:\16404173\b.h(3) : error C2496: 'B::m_b' : 'selectany' can only be applied to
>   data items with external linkage

---

Finally, Visual C++ clearly is defining the symbol (incorrectly):

R:\16404173>dumpbin /symbols b.obj
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

> ```
> Dump of file b.obj
>
> File Type: COFF OBJECT
>
> COFF SYMBOL TABLE
> 000 00AB9D1B ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
> 001 00000000 SECT1  notype       Static       | .drectve
>     Section length   2F, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
> 003 00000000 SECT2  notype       Static       | .debug$S
>     Section length   64, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
> 005 00000000 SECT3  notype       Static       | .rdata
>     Section length    4, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum B4446054, selection    2 (pick any)
> 007 00000000 SECT3  notype       External     | ?m_b@B@@2HB (public: static int const B::m_b)
> ```

Furthermore, we see that it is marked as `selectany` already.  But in the compilation unit with the actual definition:

> ```
>     Section length    4, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum B4446054
> 229 00000000 SECTB9 notype       External     | ?m_b@B@@2HB (public: static int const B::m_b)
> ```

The `(pick any)` annotation is gone.  Which is proper, this is an authoritative definition of the variable.

It's wrong for the variable to appear in `b.obj` at all.  The compiler makes the simple case (initialization inside header file) work by using the `selectany` annotation, but this hackish workaround falls apart when a real definition is provided.

---

Finally, adding `__declspec(selectany)` on the real definition, in a.cpp, works around the link error.  But I'm afraid the symbol will still be optimized away by the linker and not available during debugging.  You can temporarily use the `/OPT:NOREF` to avoid this (but it will bloat your executable, so turn that option off again before shipping).

Comment: Reading the code again, it looks like you are following this rule.  So there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @user2141130: No, your question is missing the object file name on the very front.  Where an error occurs is just as important as the error's description.

Comment: Answered, thank you.  This also answers [my previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365826/why-doesnt-the-visual-studio-2010-debugger-see-static-const-class-members).  I'm not sure what SO protocol is here but if you want to answer that with a link to here I will gladly accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to what clang will accept, the static const variable initialisation must happen in the definition rather than the declaration.

Therefore in your header you want this:

```
class B{
  public:
   static const int m_b;
};
```

And then the definition in your cpp should be like this:

```
const int B::m_b = 100;
```

Comment: How is `clang` relevant to Visual C++?