# why using list<const string> instead of list<string> gives me an error?

Tags: c++, list

I tried to initialize a list of const string but I get an error. The simply code is the following

```
#include <string>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<const std::string> l;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile I get the following error:

[image]

Can someone explain me why?
Thanks

Comment: The allocator requirements need `T` needs to be a "non-const, non-reference object type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize a static const list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154732/initialize-a-static-const-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 1):

`std::list` must have a non-const and non-volatile value type by definition. You can initialize the list itself as `const`, so the content and length isn't changeable e.g.:

```
const std::list<std::string> l = {"a","b"};
```