# Why can't we declare static variables in the class definition?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I write code that looks like

```
#include <string>
class C {
  static const std::string MY_SPECIAL_STRING = "hi";
};
```

and I try to compile it, even in C++11 mode, g++ will complain:

> static data member of type 'const std::string' must be initialized out
>   of line

Why do we have this rule?

---

I mean, I can still kind of 'cheat' and have static variables inside static methods, e.g.:

```
#include <string>
class C {
  static const std::string& MY_SPECIAL_STRING() {
    static const std::string& ss("hi");
    return ss;
  }
};
```

This way, I don't need to put a declaration in a translation unit, and I effectively have the same thing, albeit with uglier syntax.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563897/c-static-constant-string-class-member

Comment: @user1929959 The answers in that other question only addresses the 'what' and not the 'why'.

Comment: I've just read the one answer on that marked dup question, but it doesn't really address that the linker already has the mechanism to do this -- when we have static variables inside static functions of classes, that is effectively the mechanism we want. Why doesn't the compiler just conveniently do the same thing here?

Comment: To use that in-class initialization syntax, the constant must be a static const of integral or enumeration type initialized by a constant expression.
This is the restriction,

Comment: const char [] instead of const std::string would work

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy Thank you for the reply! Actually I was using std::string as illustrative purposes -- the actual type I want to use at the moment is std::regex. Also, it would be nice to have a general solution that I could apply to other similar situaitons.