# Compile Error with std::deque::erase with const members of the class

Tags: c++, stddeque

I get an compile error here and I have no idea whats wrong with the code. I am using g++ 4.9.2.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<deque>

using std::string;
using std::deque;

class Dummy {
public:
    virtual ~Dummy(){};
    Dummy():ID_("00") {};
private:

    const string ID_;
};

int main(){
    {
    deque <Dummy> waiter;
    waiter.push_back(Dummy());
    waiter.erase( waiter.begin() );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I know that removing the const removes the compilation error, but I have no idea why. Anyway, I need this const.

Comment: Please add the error message.

Comment: I have to say that, having compiled this, the output from gcc 4.9.2 is spectacularly long and unhelpful. I won't chew up the page by repeating it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[std::deque::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) expects the type of element should be [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable):

> Type requirements
>
> T must meet the requirements of MoveAssignable.

And class `Dummy` has a const member `const string ID_;`, which make it not assignable by default assignment operator.

You might make `ID_` a non-const member, or provide your own assignment operator to make it assignable. e.g.

```
Dummy& operator=(const Dummy&) { /* do nothing */ }
```

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/wFg8i6)

Comment: That's the gist of it. Removing the erase also cures the compile error.

Comment: Agreed. I got the same result, but missed the relevance of the MoveAssignable requirement - well spotted!

Comment: @songyuanyao Do you think that your solution with making it "assignable" is legal? I think there must be a reason that it should be MoveAssignable ...

Comment: @varantir It's the requirment of the method. Image that if you erase an element in middle of the `deque`, it has to move the remaining elements to fill the vacancy. That means it will call assignment operator to move their position.

Comment: @songyuanyao But If I modify the move assignable operator accordingly, I do not think the moving when erasing an element will work properly!

Comment: @varantir Not sure I understand you correctly...do you mean [this](http://ideone.com/ffiSEf)?

Answer (score 0):

you should remove the `const` prefix, so that the string can be changed:

```
string ID_;
```

or else change it to a static variable and initialize it like this:

```
class Dummy {
public:
    virtual ~Dummy(){};
    Dummy() {};
private:

    static const string ID_;
};

const string Dummy::ID_ = "00";
```

you can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564999/2082964) about const string initialisation.