# std::deque::erase, T need to be MoveAssignable, how to evade?

Tags: c++, std

As a follow up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888571/compile-error-with-stddequeerase-with-const-members-of-the-class), I wonder if there is a way to evade the MoveAssignable for std::deque::erase. Actually I have a bunch of interconnected classes with a lot of const types and references, which are far from MoveAssignable. I need to container them, but without being able to use erase this becomes meaningless. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use another collection type? A `std::list` perhaps?

Comment: Are the "const types and references" actually neccessary? You should store pointers instead of references and remove the `const` from data members (using `const` correctness on member functions means data members don't need to be `const` themselves).

Answer (score 4):

The way `std::deque` is intended to work *requires* for its contents to be relocatable (otherwise, it wouldn't require the `MoveAssignable` concept). Which means you cannot use a deque (or a vector for that matter) with non-movable types. But you can use a container which doesn't move its elements around, like `std::list` or associative containers.