# Method get a string

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to make a get method in a class medicine to get the description.
As I know of that in C++, there is no data type "String" like in Java, therefore I need to make an array of char to save the description. I couldn't find a way to make a method with return type "array of chars", I use a pointer like the following.

```
class Medicine {
public:
    char description[100] = "testing";
    char *getDescription() {
        char *p_description;
        char *p_subDescription = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(p_subDescription, description);
        p_description = p_subDescription;
        free(p_subDescription);
        return p_description;
    }
};
```

I have a question: is there any other way I can do to make the code shorter? I feel like this is too much work just for a method to get a string.

Thank,

Comment: C++ **does** have a `string` class.

Comment: Don't use malloc/free and strcpy in C++!

Comment: @manni66, and don't return a pointer to a location you just `free`d, why we are at it

Comment: [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) - this kind of pointer jiggling is tricky, and you shouldn't do it if you don't have to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563897/c-static-constant-string-class-member). Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I am sorry for this dumb question. I have learnt c++ for 2 weeks.
And can I know the reason why shouldn't I use malloc/free and strcpy in C++ @manni66?
Thank you @BartekBanachewicz, I did not find it before.
Thanks you for spending time for this.

Comment: @Someonewhohaveacat these are the old C functions. For strings use std::string. If you really have to alocate memory yourself, use the C++ functions new/delete + new[]/delete/[]. If you learnt malloc for C++ then your learning material is very bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this to be static (class-specific), the easiest way I can think of is a static, public property:

```
class Medicine {
public:
    static const std::string description;
};
const std::string Medicine::description = "testing";
```

Comment: `std::string` is not `constexpr`.

Comment: @Yuki Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to decided on your flavour of C++. If you want "C with classes", C++ very close to C, then you should be passing strings about as char *s to memory allocated with malloc. Your code is nearly correct (however you free memory then return it), but most people write a little function called strdup (in fact it's often provided, which means ironically it's best to call it mystrdup() to avoid collisions)

```
char *mystrdup(char *str)
{
   char *answer = malloc(strlen(st) +1);
   if(answer)
      strcpy(answer, str);
   return answer;
}
```

If you are writing a more modern version of C++, use the std::string class. It isn't especially efficient and it's widely criticised for being over-desinged, but it's standard. It does memory management for you, and it's easy to create one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::string` like this

```
class Medicine {
public:
  char description[100] = "testing";
    std::string getDescription() {
    return description;
  }
};
```

Comment: But why would you do that?

Comment: Why keep the `char[]` at all?!

Comment: You do not know why he has `char` buffer, as well as I do not. That is why I did not touch it.

Comment: But why do you use a 100-character array, that's not even static, to hold a string of a few bytes? I can't think of any circumstances where this solution would be an acceptable one.

Comment: Example: the class get data from database and in the database it is limited to 100 characters. But again I do not know, what the purpose of this buffer in the question, that is why I did not touch it.