# Static members erroneously initialized as empty strings

Tags: c++, initialization, static-members

I have three files:

`api.h`:

```
class HttpApi{
 public:
    static bool postData(string json);

 private:
    static  string remoteHost;
    static  string port;
    static  string url;
};
```

`api.cpp`:

```
string HttpApi::remoteHost = Config::getInstance().getRemoteServer();
string HttpApi::port = Config::getInstance().getPort();
string HttpApi::url="/api/miner";

bool HttpApi::postData(string json)
{
    //Here I print Config::getInstance.getRemoteServer(), the value is correct set here

    cout<<"Start resolve "<< remoteHost<<"   "<<port<<endl;
    cout<<"Succeed in resolving "<<endl;

}
```

and finally:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Config&  config = Config::getInstance();
    cout<<"Start loading configuration "<<endl;
    config.loadConfig("config.ini");

    HttpApi::postData("hello world");
}
```

The problem for me is that the initialization of two members `remoteHost`, `port` is invalid: at runtime, both are empty.

Here `Config` is a singleton class and it reads values from config.ini. It has some members, such as `remoteHost`, and `port`.

Why are both static members empty and how can I fix it?

Comment: [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order), perhaps? You haven't shown the code for `Config`.

Comment: The initialisation of `HttpApi::remoteHost` and `HttpApi::port` probably happens too early and at that time `Config::getInstance().getRemoteServer()` returns and empty string for whatever reason. Check that first.

Comment: Refet to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563897/c-static-constant-string-class-member

Comment: The initialisation of static member objects very much depends on how the whole thing is compiled. The first thing standard says is: The static members are initialised in the order of their definition but not declaration. The second thing standard says is: The static initialisation can occur before the first use of any object or function of the class.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/3807729

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize private static members in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/how-to-initialize-private-static-members-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one can only guess what happens.

First, static data member of classes are initialized at the very beginning of your program, in an unspecified order, before `main()` is invoked<sup>1</sup>. This means that

```
string HttpApi::remoteHost = Config::getInstance().getRemoteServer();
string HttpApi::port = Config::getInstance().getPort();
```

is evaluated before

```
config.loadConfig("config.ini");
```

Secondly, if we make the assumption that `Config::getInstance()` returns a default constructed instance before any `loadConfig` is called, and if we also assume a default constructed `Config` is only a collection of, say, empty strings, then we can say for sure that `HttpApi::remoteHost` and `HttpApi::port` will be initialized from empty strings.

Finally, a possible solution would be to drop the anti-pattern Singleton is, or define a way for `HttpApi` to use an already loaded configuration:

```
void HttpApi::load(Config const& conf) // obviously declared as static
{
    remoteHost = conf.getRemoteServer();
    port       = conf.getPort();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Config& config = Config::getInstance();
    std::cout << "Start loading configuration\n";
    config.loadConfig("config.ini");
    HttpApi::load(config);
    HttpApi::postData("hello world");
}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> This is not entirely true, for curious readers:

> #### [`[class.static.data]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static.data#6)
>
> Static data members are initialized and destroyed exactly like non-local variables (`[basic.start.static]`, `[basic.start.dynamic]`, `[basic.start.term]`).

and

> #### [`[basic.start.dynamic]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic#4)
>
> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with static storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of main or is deferred.

Comment: I think your guess is more likely correct than my suggestion of the "fiasco". But as you said, all we can do is guess.

Comment: Thanks. I have not notice the order of static member initialization. I will change my code

Comment: In addition to the singleton, I think `HttpApi` having all members `static` is a red flag.

Comment: @FredLarson OP, in only a few lines of code, provides a _forest_ of red flags ;)

Comment: @FredLarson Do you mean this is a bad design to have all static members in a class?

Comment: Typically, yes. It essentially becomes just a namespace at that point.

Comment: Thanks. So a better way is to define a namespace `HttpApi`, and then a global method `postData` in the namespace?

Comment: The quick workaround would be to wrap the static member in static member function. So, the members are initialised the first time the function is invoked.

Comment: @ArchieYalakki +1 but that would change the variables' visibility. If this is acceptable, this is an ok workaround.

Comment: @shijiexu: I'd probably just not use `static` and create an instance.