# How to make a static class to reference string variables with C++?

Tags: c#, c++, unreal-engine4

So I am trying to make a general C++ static that just holds string variables. I am using Unreal Engine 4 in this project. **I have a working solution, but am looking to see if what I do in C# can be done in C++.**

Working Solution (C++):
DFControllerGameModeBase.h

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/GameModeBase.h"
#include "DFControllerGameModeBase.generated.h"


#define MoveForwardInput        "MoveForward"
```

Implementation:

```
#include "DFControllerGameModeBase.h" 

void ADFCharacter::Play(){
.....

string text = MoveForwardInput;

}
```

**However this is what I do in C# with Unity:**

```
using System;

namespace Assets.Scripts.Helpers
{

    public static class Utilities
    {
        public static string MoveForward = "MoveForward";
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
using Assets.Scripts.Helpers;

void Play(){

string text = Utilities.MoveForward;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static constant string (class member)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563897/static-constant-string-class-member)

Comment: i don't know if this is what you really need, but you can do this using namespace and enum class. Won't be a static variable, but will fit the purpose. And you can use include guards or pragma once to avoid duplicate.

Comment: @Radagast Thanks for the direction, I have considered enums. This is more of a question of me trying to explore C++ and translating my C# sample over

Comment: @sujaygchand bruglesco's redirect link should be the better option then. good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no problem with encapsulation and will not be using the statics in Blueprint, then just using #define will do.

You also want to use capital letters for #define naming convention.

```
#define MOVE_FORWARD_INPUT "MoveForward"
```

But if you want it encapsulated and be able to call it in the Blueprint. Then you'll have to create a static helper class.

```
.h
class Utilities
{
public:
    static const FString MoveForward;

    //create BP getter function here
}

.cpp
const FString Utilities::MoveForward = "MoveForward";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, exactly what I was looking for