# How properly instantiate static field tat is another class object

Tags: c++, static

If I have in my .h file

```
class A
{
 ...
protected:
static std::mutex someMutex;
}
```

What is proper way to instantiate it in the cpp file?
Just to write

```
std::mutex A::someMutex;
```

? It works, but just such syntax where I basically declare a field twice feels a bit confusing, so I decided to doublecheck asking here, also maybe there are some other(better?) ways?

Comment: Have you tried it?  Yes, that should work.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, it works, but just such syntax where I basically declare a field twice feels a bit confusing, so I decided to doublecheck asking here, also maybe there are some other(better?) ways

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static constant string (class member)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563897/static-constant-string-class-member)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is correct but these two notations are not exactly the same thing written twice.

Inside the braces of the class (in the .h file) this is a *declaration*.
It is a kind of promise saying "I swear this exists somewhere".
This can be seen in *many* translation units (i.e. .cpp files including this .h
file).

On the other hand, what you wrote in your .cpp file is the *definition* of
this variable; it must exist exactly once in your program.

An alternative exists since C++17: inline variables.
It offers the ability to skip the definition of the static variable
in the .cpp file (useful for header-only solutions).