# Why I can't define a static field in the declaration?

Tags: c++

So it looks like I can't do this for some reason...

```
class MyClass
{
    static std::string name = "Whatever";
};
```

I don't get it, for me it would make sense to define something in the declaration, even if is static, but instead, I have to do this... ¿?¿?¿?

```
class MyClass
{
    static std::string name;
};
std::string MyClass::name = "Whatever";
```

And by the way... Isn't *name* private by default? Then why can I change its value from outside the class?

Comment: @scohe001 No, the rules are stricter for `std::string` than for `int`. Much of that page does not apply.

Comment: @Asteroids would you prefer [Static constant string (class member)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1563897/2602718) then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why I can't define a static field in the declaration?

You can!

```
#include <string>

class MyClass
{
    static inline std::string name = "Whatever";
    //     ^^^^^^
};
```

---

> Isn't name private by default? Then why can I change its value from outside the class?

You can't!

You're defining/initialising it, not changing its value.

Comment: No I can't, It says "a nonstatic data member cannot be declared as inline"

Comment: @Karlos Then your compiler is ancient, or set in ancient mode. What is it and what standard are you using?

Comment: [Live demo of it working](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da979b9296288857)

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Hang on... "nonstatic"??

Comment: yep, thats what is says, i dont know what it means though im just coming from c#

Comment: @Karlos Did you remove the `static` keyword by mistake?

Comment: nope, that joint is still there

Comment: That makes no sense.

Comment: i know, that's why im asking

Comment: I have no answer for that. That cannot happen. The compiler doesn't complain about "nonstatic" members when they're static, and VS 2019 supports inline there.

Comment: well, that's why i got written here, thx for answering though, idk, it's static, but then it's telling me that is nonstatic...

Comment: Are you sure you're rebuilding the right file?

Comment: You need to add "/std:c++17" switch (not sure about GUI) for `inline` to work on MSVC.

Comment: Yes @AsteroidsWithWings, It's an empty proyect, im just seeing how classes work in c++ compared to c#.

Comment: @sklott where ?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the Intellisense in VS 2019 (and VS 2022 for that matter) can't parse static inline members correctly and will flag them as errors. Compile your project, the compiler itself shouldn't complain.