# How do I declare static class data member which are thread local?

Tags: c++, class, static, thread-local

I have been working on a learning project in C++(11) and I want to implement something analogous to -

```
class ImpClass
{
    static __thread Foo foo;

    void doSomething()
    {
        ImpClass::foo.doSomeOtherThing();
        // do something;
    }
};
```

But compiling this results into `undefined reference to 'ImpClass::foo[abi:cxx11]'`

when using `thread_local` instead of `__thread`, it says `undefined reference to 'TLS init function for ImpClass::foo[abi:cxx11]'`.

I am using gcc compiler (version : 9.3.0)

Comment: Well, you have to define static member variables somewhere. Pick your favourite .cpp file and put the definition there. It has nothing to do with `thread_local`.

Comment: @Quimby, that worked. Thanks.

Comment: Same as here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563897/static-constant-string-class-member