# error "method is private within this context" trying to initialize static method

Tags: c++, static

I have this class (declared in the header file):

```
class HttpError
{
    static std::map<unsigned long, const char *> statusCodes;
    std::string msg;
public:
    HttpError();
};
```

And I have put this in the corresponding *.cpp file:

```
HttpError::statusCodes =  {
        {100L, "Continue" },
        {101L, "Switching Protocols" }}
```

When I compile, I got the error "statusCodes is private within this context". Yes, I know that it is private, but how it is supposed to initialize an static private member??

I've read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563897/static-constant-string-class-member) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/how-to-initialize-private-static-members-in-c), and I humbly think I have the same, but surpringsingly does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I was forgetting to declare the type of the variable being initialized, that was:

```
 std::map<unsigned long, const char *>  HttpError::statusCodes =  {
    {100L, "Continue" },
    {101L, "Switching Protocols" }};
```

When I did it, the error was solved.